# Any way to zip to list of lists?

Tags: python, arrays, list, zip

Alright, so I have two lists that look like this

```
listx = [2, 4, 5, 9, 11]
listy = [3, 5, 9, 12, 14]
```

Right now, when I do zip, I get this

```
listz = zip(listx, listy)
listz = [(2,3), (4,5), (5,9), (9, 12), (11,14)]
```

Is there any way to make this a list of lists instead of an array, like so

```
listz = [[2,3], [4,5], [5,9], [9,12], [11,14]]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need it to be a list of lists instead of a list of tuples?

Comment: I imagine he intends to change them in some way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a comprehension:

```
listz = [list(i) for i in zip(listx, listy)]
```

or generator expression:

```
listz = (list(i) for i in zip(listx, listy))
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `map` to convert the tuples to lists.

```
map(list, zip(listx, listy))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a list comprehension, and use `izip` to avoid creating an intermediary list.

```
import itertools

listz = [list(z) for z in itertools.izip(listx, listy)]
```

Comment: Just for note, on Python 3+, zip function returns a generator, no need for izip then.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from itertools import izip, imap
>>> listx = [2, 4, 5, 9, 11]
>>> listy = [3, 5, 9, 12, 14]
>>> listz = list(imap(list, izip(listx, listy)))
>>> listz
[[2, 3], [4, 5], [5, 9], [9, 12], [11, 14]]
```